# spring.config.location not able to add multiple sql file to environment

Tags: spring-boot

I have below directory structure.

```
src/main/resources/
bootstrap.yml:
spring
 config:
  location: classpath*:/sql/*.sql.xml
```

I have sql folder in `src/main/resources/` and I want to load all sql files in environment. But its not working any suggestions

Comment: As the name of the property suggests it is only a location not files. Also it is used by Spring Boot to load property files or yaml files.

Comment: it works when I add individual files but not patterns

Comment: It will not work with patterns, and as mentioned it is for Spring Boot to load property and yaml files.